# Sort certain part of a Tree store

Tags: sorting, extjs, extjs-stores

I have a tree panel. And I want to sort treeStore in 'ASC' by field 'size'.
I tried to achieve this like :

```
TreeStore.sort(property: 'size', direction: 'ASC')
```

But I want to sort store from the fifth record onward. And first 5 records should remain as it is(unaffected from sorting).Can someone guide me that how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box, so you would have to pass a special marker to the four records that you wish to keep at the top, e.g.

```
mark: "1"
mark: "2"
mark: "3"
mark: "4"
mark: "5+"
mark: "5+"
mark: "5+"
mark: "5+"
```

and then sort by that marker first:

```
TreeStore.sort([{property:'mark',direction:'ASC'},{property: 'size', direction: 'ASC'}]);
```